# Firestore in query problems

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have an array field in Firestore that looks like that `['west_coast', 'east_coast']` I want to get results if west_coast and east_coast are found in the same array from dynamic data

It works when I do it as in the example on the Firestore site.

```
const exactlyOneCoast = await citiesRef.where('region', 'in',[['west_coast', 'east_coast']]).get();
```

but since the data comes dynamically, if the place of the data in the array is different, it does not give any results.

```
const exactlyOneCoast = await citiesRef.where('region', 'in',[['east_coast', 'west_coast']]).get();
```

I want it to find it even if they change places. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of your document? Definitely both the arrays are different so one query won't match other.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array field called "region" that holds two values "east_coast" and "west_coast", then there is no way you can use the following query:

```
const exactlyOneCoast = await citiesRef.where('region', 'in',[['west_coast', 'east_coast']]).get();
```

Nor:

```
const exactlyOneCoast = await citiesRef.where('region', 'in',[['east_coast', 'west_coast']]).get();
```

Why? Because the `in` operator works **only** against a field of type String and **not** against a field of type array. So if you have a field of type String, the `in` query returns documents where the given field matches any of the comparison values.

If you need to check if a particular value exists in an array, then you should use the [array_contains](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any) operator. Since you [cannot chain multiple such calls](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#query_limitations), then you should perform multiple separate database calls.

Comment: const exactlyOneCoast = await citiesRef.where('region', 'in',[['west_coast', 'east_coast'], ['east_coast', 'west_coast']]).get();  Will it work if I try this?

Comment: Not, won't. You should only use the `array_contains` operator.

Comment: You should only use the array_contains operator. you said but i have no chance to do this it is not used in a row in a single query

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand your last comment. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: Hey Alex. I don't think it helps, why are you pushing so hard? You told me it wouldn't be like that, I know that too. You didn't give me a solution

Answer (score 0):

The query you are doing is looking for an exact array match [[docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#array-contains-any)]

> You can use an array value as a comparison value for in, but unlike array-contains-any, the clause matches for an exact match of array length, order, and values.

If you drop one set of brackets, it will return if region is either `west_coast` or `east_coast`

```
citiesRef.where('region', 'in',['east_coast', 'west_coast'])
```

The `in`, `array_contains`, and `array_contains_any` operators are logical `OR` searches, so if you want to return documents where an array (in your document) contains both elements, then you need to do a [compound query](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#compound_queries). However, you cannot do multiple `array_contains` queries. You would instead need to do multiple queries separately and then build your own logic around them.

---

Edit: Fixed the chaining array_contains issue that I forgot about.

Comment: Also from the documentation: [You can use at most one array-contains clause per query.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#:~:text=results%20only%20once.-,You%20can%20use%20at%20most%20one,-array%2Dcontains%20clause). So 2nd way won't work iirc.

Comment: 2nd query will not work as in the comment.
1st query is not what I want it won't work on it